# Solving $L_2 = I - xe_2^T$ for $x$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

$$L_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$e_2^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 &0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to find the value of $x$ given this equation

$$L_2 = I - xe_2^T$$

I figured out that its a $3 \times 1$ matrix since we need to create a $3 \times 3$ matrix but rest I'm not sure how to find

Comment: Is $e_2^T$ the transpose of $e_2$?

Comment: yes $e_2$ is the 2-th-column of the identity matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L_2-I =
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus you are looking for $$x=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$ such that $$xe_2^T =  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that $$xe_2^T= \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}[0,1,0]=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & a & 0 \\
    0 & b & 0 \\
    0 & c & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore  we have $$x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=e_3$$